# How to add separate Android Activities that are incompatible

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mapbox

I'm trying to get two separate views added to an existing Android application. Previously, there were no problems having both of them added, but on the new branch we were provided, they're completely incompatible.

One is the MapBox SDK, which is added with the following lines in the gradle.build file per their documentation:

```
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.3.0')
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:3.3.0')
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:2.2.9')
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.15.0')
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.15.0')
```

The other is the MapBox WorldScale AR, created by loading their example scene in Unity, exporting to an Android project, and following this guide to create a library and embed the project: https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a

The notable line in the build.gradle file for AR is: `implementation (project(":WorldViewAR-release"))`

As is, I get errors about various parts of Lokio being already included. If I comment out one or the other, it assembles just fine. I've tried the following to exclude them from each other:

```
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.3.0') {
    exclude module: ':WorldViewAR-release'
}
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:3.3.0') {
    exclude module: ':WorldViewAR-release'
}
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:2.2.9')  {
    exclude module: ':WorldViewAR-release'
}
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.15.0')  {
    exclude module: ':WorldViewAR-release'
}
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.15.0')  {
    exclude module: ':WorldViewAR-release'
}
implementation ('android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1')


implementation (project(":WorldViewAR-release")) {
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-sdk'
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-sdk-services'
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-services'
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-navigation'
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-navigation-ui'
}
```

Additionally, I've tried installing the MapBox SDK in a different Android project and an Android Library module, but then I'm unable to access any of the features in the SDK in the main app.

Am I missing something with adding the exclusions, or is there another way to install the SDK in a separate module that will allow it to be accessible in the main app?